# Trying to get a result not displaying

Tags: php, html, mysqli, echo

I'm just trying to get something basic to appear for now and it's not working. It should display 1 on the screen. Is my logic wrong? I paste my statement in console and get 1.

```
<?php

$sql = mysqli_query("Select moist_measure_avail from sigh_in_account where moist_measure_avail = '1'");

$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

echo $result['moist_measure_avail'];
```

Comment: `mysqli_query` takes a connection object as its first argument. You should enable error reporting to help with your debugging.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments

Comment: Here's a basic example of how to establish a connection and use it in `mysqli_query`: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357905/mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should have to create a connection

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost "," root","","dbname");
?>
```

And then you have to include the conn variable in your query

```
$sql = mysqli_query( $conn, " SELECT moist_measure_avail from sigh_in_account WHERE moist_measure_avail = '1'");
```

The sql statements must be either all caps or all small

Comment: `sql statements must be either all caps or all small` is not true.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysqli_query("Select moist_measure_avail from sigh_in_account where moist_measure_avail = '1'");
```

pass connection as first param in above method. something like this

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"Select moist_measure_avail from sigh_in_account where moist_measure_avail = '1'");
```

where $conn is mysql connection